# Is there a round off function in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, rounding

I need roundoff function in J2ME. Math.round() does not seem to exist. Please provide some assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can use another approach:

```
float value;
int base; //base to round

int round_down=(int )((int )(value/base))*base;
int round_up=(int )((int )(value/base+0.5))*base;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ceil() or Math.floor()` probably but these again are available only for CLDC 1.1 :)